# htaccess получить GET параметры

Tags: .htaccess, get, поддомены

Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я получаю в **htaccess** GET параметры основного домена и перенаправляю на поддомен?

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} admin$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1 [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin.php?r=user/account/login$ [NC]
#RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} http://user.inter-ural.ru/site/login/$1 [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(\/?.*)$ http://user.inter-ural.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ну тут 50 на 50. Либо правильно, либо нет. Например, где условие, которое говорит, что это параметры основного домена?

Comment: А как тогда правильно сделать?

Comment: Так в итоге ваша конфигурация не рабочая?

Comment: Моя как раз работает не корректно.